# How can I change entermode br instead of p in ckeditor5?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

In ckeditor5 by cdn to include ckeditor.js I would like to change entermode that `<br>` instead of `<p></p>`? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you wnat to use `<BR>` as change line code in CKeditor 5, then just use "Shift+Enter" can make it happen.

Here is the code if you still want to make `<P>` display likes `<BR>` one's:

```
p {
   margin: 0;
}
```

Seriously, I got same problem like your's......then I found Shift+Enter.

Answer (score 1):

You could handle the `enter` event and make it trigger `shiftEnter` instead.

```js
    editor.editing.view.document.on(
        'enter',
        ( evt, data ) => {
            editor.execute('shiftEnter');
            //Cancel existing event
            data.preventDefault();
            evt.stop();
     }, {priority: 'high' });

source: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/1141#issuecomment-403403526
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did in PHP is the following:

```
$replaceClosingTag = str_replace('</p>', '<br>', $_POST['message']);
$emailMessageText = str_replace('<p>', '', $replaceClosingTag);
```

I replaced the closing tag with a `<br>` and the opening tag with an empty space.
It is dirty but it worked for me. Probally with javascript you can do something similar.

And for the editor margin style I used this:

```
.ck.ck-editor__editable_inline p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Because I use a CDN and this overrides that class.

The question is 2 years old but hopefully this helps for someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

My requirement is the opposite of yours.

I'm using `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue` and a custom editor, provided for reference.

Custom editor:

```js
import ClassicEditorBase from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor';

import Essentials from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials';
import Enter from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-enter/src/enter';
import ShiftEnter from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-enter/src/shiftenter';
import Paragraph from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph';
import Custom1 from './plugin/custom1';
import Custom2 from './plugin/custom2';

export default class ClassicEditor extends ClassicEditorBase {}

ClassicEditor.builtinPlugins = [
  Essentials,
  Paragraph,
  Enter,
  ShiftEnter,
  Custom1,
  Custom2,
];

ClassicEditor.defaultConfig = {
  toolbar: {
    items: [],
  },
  language: 'en',
};
```

vue template:

```xml
<ckeditor
  v-model="content"
  :editor="editorBuild"
  @ready="editorOnReady"
  @input="handleEditorInput"
  @blur="handleEditorBlur"
/>
```

Vue setup script:

```js
import ClassicEditor from '@/ckeditor';
    
const editorBuild = ClassicEditor;
const editor = ref();
    
function editorOnReady(editorObj) {
  editorObj.keystrokes.set('Shift+Enter', 'enter');
  editor.value = editorObj;
}
```